# scatter plot over boxplot using Matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, boxplot, scatter

I've plotted a simple boxplot of a vector y (1xN) using Matlab. I used multiple grouping variables: x1, x2, x3

x1 (1xN) represents length (0.5, 1 , 2 or 3)

x2 (1xN) represents gauge (26 or 30)

x3 (1xN cell array) represents the name of the vendor.

```
close all; clc;

N = 1000;


% measurements values: they represent some kind of an
% electrical characteristic of a cable.
y = randn(N,1);

% each cable being measured can be of length 1m, 2m, or 3m:
x1 = randi(3,N,1);

% each cable being measured have a gauge of  1awg or 2awg:
x2 = randi(2,N,1);

% each cable can be produced by a different vendor. for instance: 'SONY' or
% 'YAMAHA' 

x3 = cell(N,1);

for ii = 1:N
   if mod(ii,3) == 0
       x3{ii} = 'SONY';
   else
       x3{ii} = 'YAMAHA';
   end
end

figure(1)
boxplot(y,{x1,x2,x3});
```

I would like to plot a scatter plot over this boxplot in order to show the relevant values of y that create the boxplot, but I could not find a function that groups the values as the boxplot function does.

the closest thing I've found is the following [function](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/10/07/box-plot-scatter-plot/) but it only accepts a single grouping variable.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box of the boxplot is determined by the IQR. The data between boxes and outliers is everything in a range of 1.5*IQR from the upper and lower quartile. You can filter the data manually.

For instance...

```
% data generation 
data=randn(100,3);

%% 
datas=sort(data);
datainbox=datas(ceil(end/4)+1:floor(end*3/4),:);

[n1 n2]=size(datainbox);

figure(1);clf
boxplot(data); hold on
plot(ones(n1,1)*[1 2 3],datainbox,'k.')

%% 
% All datapoints coincide now horizontally. Consider adding a little random
% horizontal play to make them not coincide:

figure(2);clf
boxplot(data); hold on
plot(ones(n1,1)*[1 2 3]+.4*(rand(n1,n2)-.5),datainbox,'k.')

%%
% If you want to add all data between boxes and outliers too, do something like:

dataoutbox=datas([1:ceil(end/4) floor(end*3/4)+1:end],:);
n3=size(dataoutbox,1);
% calculate quartiles
dataq=quantile(data,[.25 .5 .75]);
% calculate range between box and outliers = between 1.5*IQR from quartiles
dataiqr=iqr(data);
datar=[dataq(1,:)-dataiqr*1.5;dataq(3,:)+dataiqr*1.5];
dataoutbox(dataoutbox<ones(n3,1)*datar(1,:)|dataoutbox>ones(n3,1)*datar(2,:))=nan;

figure(3);clf
boxplot(data); hold on
plot(ones(n1,1)*[1 2 3]+.4*(rand(n1,n2)-.5),datainbox,'k.')
plot(ones(n3,1)*[1 2 3]+.4*(rand(n3,n2)-.5),dataoutbox,'.','color',[1 1 1]*.5)
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, but as you can see from the example code i have just added, i use many grouping vectors, some of them are strings.

Answer (score 0):

found a simple solution:

I edited the signature of the 'boxplot' function so it will return 'groupIndexByPoint' in addition to 'h':

**function [h,groupIndexByPoint] = boxplot(varargin)**

groupIndexByPoint is an internal variable used by 'boxplot'.

and now simply add 4 lines to the original code:

```
N = 1000;

% measurements values: they represent some kind of an
% electrical characteristic of a cable.
y = randn(N,1);

% each cable being measured can be of length 1m, 2m, or 3m:
x1 = randi(3,N,1);

% each cable being measured have a gauge of  1awg or 2awg:
x2 = randi(2,N,1);

% each cable can be produced by a different vendor. for instance: 'SONY' or
% 'YAMAHA' 

x3 = cell(N,1);

for ii = 1:N
   if mod(ii,3) == 0
       x3{ii} = 'SONY';
   else
       x3{ii} = 'YAMAHA';
   end
end

figure(1);
hold on;
[h,groups] = boxplot(y,{x1,x2,x3});
scattering_factor = 0.3;
scaterring_vector = (rand(N,1)-0.5)*scattering_factor;
groups_scattered = groups + scaterring_vector;
plot(groups_scattered,y,'.g');
```